# React SVG, issue with combining SVG's

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

If I want to combine multiple SVG parts into a single component, the issue is that every React component has to return a single parent element.

```
class ComponentA extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <svg>
        <Part1 />
        <Part2 />

      </svg>
    )
  }
}


class Part1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <defs>
        <linearGradient...>
        <etc...>
      </defs>
      <g>
        <path...>
        <text...>
      </g>
)
  }
}


class Part2 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <defs>
        <linearGradient...>
        <etc...>
      </defs>
      <g>
        <circle...>
        <path...>
        <path...>
      </g>
)
  }
}
```

As we can see, in order to combine multiple SVG components into one component, we have to return both **defs** and **g** tags, and possibly also *title* and maybe others. This breaks the React rule that every component needs to return only one parent element. How do we solve this?

Comment: use react 16, that has no such limitation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [React 16](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html) or wrap `defs` and `g` with `svg` tag, like this:

```
class Part1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <svg>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient...>
        <etc...>
      </defs>
      <g>
        <path...>
        <text...>
      </g>
    </svg>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same thing: Syntax error: /src/svg/PlateSVG.js: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (111:8)

Comment: Oh I see, in React 16 that is now an actual array, so you need to put commas between elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using React 16 you might want to try

```
<React.Fragment>
  <div>
    <p>Thing 1</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Thing 2</p>
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
```